# JavaScript Not loading for paginated results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using tablesorter to paginate results in a table.  I've also got a tooltip on one of the columns to show the time it was approved.  The first 10 results in the table (loaded by default) will display the tooltip correctly.  If I switch to the next page, hovering will show the default browser title tooltip, instead of the one being triggered by JS.  I believe this is because of the way the JS is being loaded, and not for the content that is initially hidden by the pagination.  Here's how I'm calling the tooltip:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                     if ($("[rel=tooltip]").length) {
                     $("[rel=tooltip]").tooltip();
                     }
                   });
```

And just to show the links:

```
//This link displays my fancy tooltip correctly//
<a href="#" style="color:#000;" rel="tooltip" title="Monday January 28th 2013 12:11 PM">

//This link does not//
<a href="#" style="color:#000;" rel="tooltip" title="Monday January 28th 2013 01:25 PM">
```

Like I said the only difference between the two rows is that one is loaded when the page loads, the other is triggered by either changing the amount of rows visible on the page, or going to the next page (which by the way is JS, doesn't actually change page location).  The rows are generated from MySQL, while the first ten work, none after that do.
Is my conclusion correct?  Could I be missing something else?  Thanks for any advice!

Edit:  I would add that, contributing to my confusion, the paginator does not actually hide the rows from the html source.  It just does not display them in the browser window.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your tooltip() is just working on the FIRST entry in the resulting list.

```
$("[rel=tooltip]")
```

This ALWAYS returns a list, if only ONE is found, its just "nice" that any functions are working correctly.

to make it work, try to loop over every one

```
$(function(){
    $("[rel=tooltip]").each(function(){
        $(this).tooltip();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is, you are loading pages via AJAX. In this case, you have to recall the tooltip definition on success of AJAX call. You can do this as follows,

```
function initTooltip(){
if ($("[rel=tooltip]").length) {
                     $("[rel=tooltip]").tooltip();
                     }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
                     initTooltip();
                   });

$.ajax({
 /* some code */
 success: function(){
initTooltip();
}});
```

Note: This is not entire code. This will give an idea how to handle your issue.